# Sharepoint workflow. How to assign two or more field to one user?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

Need to send email to workshop owner after audit. He may have more than one auditable place. How do I make assign workshop1 and workshop2 to user1? And so on. After that how to send email if workshop1 has been audited? I am new to this so lacking of experience in workflows.

I can do this:

If Current Item:AuditablePlace equals workshop1

Email user1

And I have 32 places. So to do 32 steps is kinda useless

Comment: For one I solved it with bunch of if's